# Dynamic link in ios ota manifest

Tags: ios, plist, ota

I'm working on an application where I can use over the air deployment for iOS applications.

### At runtime generated .plist

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>assets</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>kind</key>
                        <string>software-package</string>
                        <key>url</key>
                        <string><![CDATA[https://myapp.com/file/d8A5s]]></string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>metadata</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                    <string>com.myapp.example</string>
                    <key>bundle-version</key>
                    <string>1</string>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software</string>
                    <key>title</key>
                    <string>App Name</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

You'll notice that the `<url>` tag is not a direct link to the file, it is a url that sends a redirect with a direct link to the file. When I change these lines to a direct link to the file, the installation succeeds.

```
 <key>url</key>                      
 <string><![CDATA[https://myapp.com/file/file.ipa]]></string>
```

**I want to do this without a direct URL to the file in the manifest**.

The content type `https://myapp.com/file/d8A5s` returns is `application/octet-stream` and I am able to download the file when I use my desktop browser to navigate to the URL.

Any help would be appreciated and I'd be happy to provide additional information.